# Javascript subtract double numbers

Tags: javascript

Javascript says **0.7-0.2** is equal to **0.49999999999999994**.

The case is the following:

```js
var change = 0.7 - 0.2;

switch (change) {
    if (change.toFixed(2) >= 1) {
        ...
    }
    else if (change.toFixed(2) >= 0.50) {
        ...
    }
    else if (change.toFixed(2) >= 0.20) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

By using **.toFixed()** method, the problem is solved but is there another way, instead of using **.toFixed()** n-times;

Comment: Argh, this is probably more relevant: [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1458633)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder could you please also add the other link I posted? I think it's more relevant here.

Comment: @VLAZ - Already had done. :-) I marked the dupe with the other but went looking for that (wish I'd seen your comment!), as it's the "what to do about it" part of this.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks a bunch anyway. I meant to link the "how to deal" but I copied the wrong URL and didn't check when pasting.